# How to check if datetime value is greater than previous value in loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, infragistics

I am using infragistics controls here . How to validate and check if datatime value of current is greater than previous datatime values.

In the loop i have list of `Dim datePicker As UltraDateTimeEditor = o` so i need to check for every loop if the current datepicker value is greater than previous one

Point to remember ...some of the datapicker values may be Nothing. So we should not compare with those.

```
 For Each o As Object In UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls
    If TypeOf (o) Is UltraDateTimeEditor Then
      Dim datePicker As UltraDateTimeEditor = o
      Dim datevalue As Object = datePicker.Value
    End If
 Next
```

Comment: Turn Option Strict On you will see some changes more than likely...

Comment: Another curious notion about "previous".  Just because it pops out of the loop first doesnt mean it should have a value "before" the later ones.  If there are 3, testing for valid dates is just 2 If statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a variable which is defined outside the loop so that you can hold the previous value in that variable and compare the current value with the previous one. and at the end of each iteration previous value should be updated with the current value since it will be the previous for the next iteration; The following code will help you:

```
Dim prevDatevalue As Object = Nothing
For Each o As Object In UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls
    If TypeOf (o) Is UltraDateTimeEditor Then
      Dim datePicker As UltraDateTimeEditor = o
      Dim datevalue As Object = datePicker.Value
      If prevDatevalue <> Nothing Then
         If prevDatevalue < datevalue Then
            ' Do something Previous value is Lesser
         Else
            ' Do something else Previous value is greater
         End If  
      End IF      
         prevDatevalue = datePicker.Value 
    End If
Next
```

Comment: VB doesn't have a `Null`, Perhaps you meant `Nothing`?

Comment: @theB: Thanks for correcting me; It help me to improve my answer. I have updated the answer

Comment: @un-lucky You are perfect !